# Having Issue on Using Switch Case with Checkbox in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/rovkk2uL/3/) and let me know how I can use JS Switch Case in order to change page background, properly?

As you can see from the demo I am getting `c1` in all selected check boxes?

```js
 $("#doIt").on("click", function(){
    var check = $('input:checkbox[name=cc]');
    if($(check).is(':checked')){
       
         var id = $(check).attr('id');
        switch (id) {
            case 'c1':
                $("body").css("background-color", "yellow");
                  console.log(id);
                break;
             case 'c2':
                $("body").css("background-color", "green");
                  console.log(id);
                break;
             case 'c3':
                $("body").css("background-color", "pink");
                console.log(id);
                break;
        }
    }
    else{
        alert('Un Checked');
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc" />
<label for="c1"><span></span>Check Box 1</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="cc" />
<label for="c2"><span></span>Check Box 2</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="c3" name="cc" />
<label for="c3"><span></span>Check Box 3</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="c4" name="cc" />
<label for="c4"><span></span>Check Box 4</label><br />

<button id="doIt" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to only query for inputs already checked.

```js
 $("#doIt").on("click", function(){
    var check = $('input:checked:checkbox[name=cc]');
    if($(check).is(':checked')){
       
         var id = $(check).attr('id');
        switch (id) {
            case 'c1':
                $("body").css("background-color", "yellow");
                  console.log(id);
                break;
             case 'c2':
                $("body").css("background-color", "green");
                  console.log(id);
                break;
             case 'c3':
                $("body").css("background-color", "pink");
                console.log(id);
                break;
        }
    }
    else{
        alert('Un Checked');
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc" />
<label for="c1"><span></span>Check Box 1</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="cc" />
<label for="c2"><span></span>Check Box 2</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="c3" name="cc" />
<label for="c3"><span></span>Check Box 3</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="c4" name="cc" />
<label for="c4"><span></span>Check Box 4</label><br />

<button id="doIt" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks depperm this is working, can you please also let me know is there any way to create case of combination of selections? like c1 & c2 then background = blue?

Comment: @Suffii You have to use `if()` for that. `if ($("#c1").is(":checked") && $("#c2").is(":checked"))`

Comment: @ Barmar Thanks again but I was hoping to dothisont using  nesting if statements and to be honest that's why I tried to use the switch case insted of If(s)

Comment: I am not sure but some thing like this http://jsfiddle.net/d7nae6xL/28/  As you can see there is case like `case '.checkbox1.checkbox2':`

Comment: Here is a fiddle that will change color depending on what is checked or not, http://jsfiddle.net/depperm/wk43w2xt/, with combos

Answer (score 2):

You are only checking the first match in your code. Instead, you should use the `.each` method to check all of the checkboxes:

```
$("#doIt").on("click", function(){
    $('input:checkbox[name=cc]').each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){

            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            switch (id) {
                case 'c1':
                    $("body").css("background-color", "yellow");
                      console.log(id);
                    break;
                 case 'c2':
                    $("body").css("background-color", "green");
                      console.log(id);
                    break;
                 case 'c3':
                    $("body").css("background-color", "pink");
                    console.log(id);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else{
            alert('Un Checked');
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
var id = $(check).attr('id');
```

isn't doing what you think. It returns the attribute of the first checkbox, not the one that's checked.

You should loop over all the checkboxes, test whether that one is checked, and get its ID.

```js
$("#doIt").on("click", function() {
  $('input:checkbox[name=cc]').each(function(i, check) {
    if ($(check).is(':checked')) {
      var id = $(check).attr('id');
      switch (id) {
        case 'c1':
          $("body").css("background-color", "yellow");
          console.log(id);
          break;
        case 'c2':
          $("body").css("background-color", "green");
          console.log(id);
          break;
        case 'c3':
          $("body").css("background-color", "pink");
          console.log(id);
          break;
      }
    } else {
      alert('Un Checked');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc" />
<label for="c1"><span></span>Check Box 1</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="cc" />
<label for="c2"><span></span>Check Box 2</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="c3" name="cc" />
<label for="c3"><span></span>Check Box 3</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="c4" name="cc" />
<label for="c4"><span></span>Check Box 4</label>
<br />

<button id="doIt" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Note that if multiple boxes are checked, it will set the background color based on the last one. And if there are any unchecked boxes, it will produce an alert for each of them. I'm not sure what you really want for these cases. If these should be mutually exclusive, you probably should be using radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks Bramar,  but I am getting alert unchecked even when a check box is selected!

Comment: Because it's testing each checkbox. If it's checked, it changes the background color, if it's unchecked it alerts.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but [name="cc"] must have quotes, and will select all checkboxes. Try this instead:

```js
$("#doIt").on("click", function(){
    var check = $('input[name="cc"]:checked');
    if(check.length > 0){
       
         var id = $(check).attr('id');
        switch (id) {
            case 'c1':
                $("body").css("background-color", "yellow");
                  console.log(id);
                break;
             case 'c2':
                $("body").css("background-color", "green");
                  console.log(id);
                break;
             case 'c3':
                $("body").css("background-color", "pink");
                console.log(id);
                break;
        }
    }
    else{
        alert('Un Checked');
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="c1" name="cc" /><label for="c1">Yellow</label>
<input type="radio" id="c2" name="cc" /><label for="c2">Green</label>
<input type="radio" id="c3" name="cc" /><label for="c3">Pink</label>
<br>
<button type="button" id="doIt">Do it!</button>
```